# Como retornar el ancho de una imagen con Javascript

Tags: javascript

estaría agradecido de su ayuda, tengo la siguiente función, la cual devuelve el ancho de una imagen a partir de un input

```
function loadImage(imagen) {
        var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var img = new Image();
        let ancho,alto;
        img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(imagen);
        img.onload = function () {
            ancho = img.width;
            alto = img.height;
            return ancho;
        }
    }
```

Pero cuando intento mostrar el ancho de la imagen en un alert devuelve siempre indefinido

```
$('#imagenes').change(function () {
            var imagen = document.getElementById("imagenes").files;
            for (x = 0; x < imagen.length; x++) {
                alert(loadImage(imagen[x]))
            }
        });
```

Las imagenes se cargan en un input file

```
<input type="file" id="imagenes" accept=".jpg" multiple>
```

Comment: Podrias añadir también tu html, de esta manera será mas sencillo ayudarte

Comment: pregunta editada

Comment: Estas haciendo `alert` del resultado de `loadImage`, y `loadImage` no devuelve nada... Por eso imprime undefined

Comment: En lugar del `return ancho;` ponle un `alert(ancho);` allí, pues el **img.onload** se procesa después del `alert(loadImage(imagen[x]))` y por eso no recibe el **return** a tiempo. Y si lo que necesitas es ese valor para procesarlo despues de la carga del onload entonces usa promesas con **async/await** o **then** (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399223/async-await-in-image-loading).